# Change path of pip and pip3

Tags: python, windows, cmd, command-line, pip

I want to create a user path to install packages installed by `pip` or `pip3` for python 3.7.2, for that, I noticed that `C:\Users\VVK\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages` by `py -m site --user-site` and,

I wish to update it by `C:\Users\VVK\AppData\Roaming\Python37\Scripts`, How is this possible?

I am using Microsoft Windows 10 64-bit.

Comment: Use `pipenv` like virtual environments.

Comment: @adnbsr How would that be relevant to this particular question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Python37\site-packages` is used to install **libraries** while `Python37\Scripts` is used to install **programs**. The latter should not be used for package installation. Packages when installed should install their programs (executable scripts) into `Python37\Scripts` themselves.

Comment: Differentiate between a library, a package, a program and what is their order of preference?, For eg, a library contains a collection of packages, a package contains a collection of programs. Please! refer the web link at https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/, in that link please read this section, in the webpage, On Windows, you can find the user base binary directory by running py -m site --user-site and replacing site-packages with Scripts. For example, this could return C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python36\site-packages so you would need to set your PATH to include.

Comment: The problem is that the word *package* is heavily overloaded. A package is a directory with file `__init__.py`; every `*.py` is a module; packages and modules can be imported with `import`. But a package is also a distribution format (egg or wheel). A library is a set of packages (in the 1st sense). And a package (2nd) contains libraries and executable scripts. When a package is installed libraries go to `site-packages` directories (system-wide, or user-owned, or in a virtialenv) while scripts go to `Scripts` directory. Scripts are program to execute; they import packages (1st) and modules.

Comment: Thank You, Sir, Now I got a Clear cut idea.